# htaccess - redirect directory address to exact page in it

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Sorry if I am using wrong terminology, while writing this question. I have a page in the directory on my website:

```
lorumipsum.com/dir/index.php
```

I would like to redirect to that page everyone, who would write address

```
lorumipsum.com/dir
```

in their browsers. How would would I do that? I tried writing in htaccess this line:

```
Redirect 301 /dir lorumipsum.com/dir/index.php
```

but it does not appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your [DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) contains `index.php`